# PHP: GET Variables on Mod Rewritten URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass parameters and use the `GET` function in PHP on a URL that has already been rewritten using mod rewrite.

I have this in my HTACCESS file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/$  ?action=search [L]
```

If I have a URL like `http://www.example.com/search/?q=test` I'm unable to get any of the parameters which I suspect is due to me already rewriting the URL!?

I've tried using the `QSA` flag like below but still haven't been able to get it working.

```
RewriteRule ^search/?$  ?action=search [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your RewriteRules to use the [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (Query String Append) flag (without the `?` character in the rule):

```
RewriteRule ^search/$  ?action=search [L,QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag tells Apache to preserve anything appended to the URL:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> `RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]`
>
> With the `[QSA]`
>   flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to
>   `/page.php?page=123&one=two`. Without the `[QSA]` flag, that same request
>   will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query
>   string will be discarded.

In addition, the `^search/$` rule is never reached, because it is overridden by this one: `RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L]` (which has the `L` flag). You need to update your entire `.htaccess` file as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^search/$  ?action=search [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So I don't need the `?` (`^search/?$`) in the rewrite rule once I use the `QSA` flag?

Comment: @llanato That's correct. The RewriteRule should be added without the `?` char.

Comment: I've an updated question further to this rewrite rule in the OT if you have a minute or two to spare any advice please.

Comment: @llanato You cannot ignore a query parameter, I'm afraid. You'd need to handle that another way.

Comment: Wasn't me, I see this from time to time, some people just don't seem to understand how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

With `QSA` flag, you should swap bottom 2 rules with an additional condition in `search` rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)action=search(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ ?action=search [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```