# Mod-Rewrite: Ignore/exclude parameter when using QSA flag

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to pass parameters and use the `GET` function in PHP on a URL that has already been rewritten using mod rewrite, this is a follow on question from [PHP: GET Variables on Mod Rewritten URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502265/php-get-variables-on-mod-rewritten-url).

This is what I have at present:

```
RewriteRule ^search/$  ?action=search [L,QSA]
```

I would like the URL to only show as `search/?q=test&p=1` instead of `search/?action=search&q=test&p=1` which is what the above rewrite rule gives me, is there a way to tell it to ignore the first parameter on the rule or to ignore a specific parameter?

```
RewriteRule ^search/?q=([^/]+)&p=([0-9])$ ?action=search&q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Query string isnt part of match in RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule with %{THE_REQUEST} variable to match against the full request line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search/\?action=[^&]+q=([^&]+)&p=([^&\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/?q=%1&p=%2 [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect

- ?action=foo&q=bar&p=1

to

- ?q=bar&p=1

And the following rule will then rewrite :

- ?q=bar&p=1

to its orignal location

- ?action=foo&q=bar&p=1

  RewriteRule ^search/$  ?action=search [L,QSA]